# Applying math formule to Pandas Series elements

Tags: python, pandas, series

Variables `data,` `maxs` and `mins` are Pandas Series with the same indexes.

I want to match the elements of the three variables by indexes.

How can I apply this function properly ?

```
def denormalize(data, maxs, mins):
    return (maxs - data) / (maxs - mins)
```

Comment: What's wrong with your code?

Comment: The results of the formula are wrong.

Comment: If you use `pd.concat([data, maxs, mins], axis=1)` first, you should have a dataframe that will match up correctly (then just use the formula, but with columns).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC:

> The results of the formula are wrong.

```
def denormalize(data, maxs, mins):
    return (mins - maxs) * data + maxs
```

This is the reverse formula of `normalize`: `(maxs - data) / (maxs - mins)`

Comment: What if my normalization formula is  (data - mins) /(maxs - mins ) ?
Should the reverse formula be like : (maxs - data) / (maxs - mins)  ?

Comment: `(maxs - mins) * data + mins`?